# Generating an html tag from a datasource using SQL

Tags: html, sql, image, insert, datasource

We're doing an SQL assignment, using a web form to display information and then add values from the form.

Part of the assignment requires us to use a radio button list and link it to a database table, which ive done. It also wants us to generate a photo relating to the text of each radio button. For example:

- Apple (picture of apple)
- Banana (picture of banana)

But it all has to come from the database itself.

We were given the hint to bind the datasource to the database table and then in the SQL SELECT statement, use a html tag to insert the image.

For example the database has 3 columns: Fruit_Code, Fruit_Name and Fruit_Image. In the Fruit_Image column we store the name of the fruit image (e.g apple.jpg).

Then from there when we use the SELECT statement, it goes:

```
SELECT Fruit_Name, Fruit_Name + ' ' + '<img src = "+'/Images/' + Fruit_Image" + />'
FROM Fruit_Table
```

However whenever i try to do this i cant seem to get it to work. The image has to come from the database in some way and has to be at the end of the radio button text.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're trying to craft a select statement that will output the html code?

Comment: SELECT Fruit_Name, Fruit_Name + '<img src="Path/To/Images/Folder/' + Fruit_Name + '.jpg" />' AS html FROM Fruit_Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the string escaping slightly off on your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT Fruit_Name
     , Fruit_Name + ' <img src=''/Images/' + Fruit_Image + '''/>'
FROM Fruit_Table
```

Added the extra escaping for the path as pointed out by @Goat_CO

Comment: you need double quotes around the path, no?  <img src = "/Images/banana.jpg">